# gcloud deploy php application

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud, app.yaml

I want to upload and run my php application on google cloud with the following folder structure:

[image]

The yaml file looks like below:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php

- url: /css
  static_dir: css
```

When I deploy it runs the index.php file, but does not attach any css or js file. What should be the structure of yaml file so that it accepts css and js files from css and js folder ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (the order of handlers is important)

```
application: <your-app-id-goes-here>
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: .*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Hi @Tom, Thanks for your answer. Yes, order of the handlers is important. I want to use another php file (script) for making ajax requests. I have added the following below the handler for index.php :
- url: /api
  script: api.php
But it does not work. Do you know the reason ?

Comment: The ".*" handler must be last. Add your AJAX handler just above it?